# no module named 'pip._vendor.packaging'

Tags: python, pip, debian, pipenv-install

I have been trying to run this command `pipenv install` for a python file that requires python 3.8.7. It proceeds to give the error `from pip._vendor.packaging.utils import canonicalize_name. no module named 'pip._vendor.packaging`. I have installed python 3.8 and updated pip. Tried requesting resources, removing python and reinstalling it and still receive the same error. I am fairly new to the OS Linux and Debian dist.